# extract latitude/longitude from specific string

Tags: php

I have this specific string:

```
{"latitude":46.57637,"longitude":26.91551}
```

I want to extract both coordinates, each coordinate to assign and display separately, like:

```
<?php
echo $lat;
echo $long;
?>
```

Anyone have any idea?

Many thanks!

Comment: This seems json array. Is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

    $json = json_decode('{"latitude":46.57637,"longitude":26.91551}');
    echo $json->latitude;
    echo $json->longitude;
?>
```

Using json decode you can archive. more details [php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can decode the json array like below

```
$decodeData=json_decode({"latitude":46.57637,"longitude":26.91551});
lat=$decodeData->latitude;
lng=$decodeData->longitude';
```